# Importing large data from blogger

Tags: import, export, bulk-import

My backup data from  blogger is 56.3MB large. I tried importing using the Wordpress Blogger plugin. Because the data is too large, I had to configure my php.ini to increase the value of three variables: `post_max_size=100M`, `upload_max_file_size=100M` and `memory_limit=1280M`

I also changed the permission to my wp-content folder recursively to 777. i.e. `chmod 777 -R wp-content/`

But I still cannot import the data to wordpress. It shows the following screen and nothing seems to be going on. There is no error in the console log as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `upload_max_filesize` is much smaller than your `post_max_filesize` which means that even though you can `POST` 100MB of data, PHP will only accept files in that `POST` data which are 8MB or less. Try increasing this limit.

Secondly, are you sure that your `php.ini` is being loaded by your host? Not all hosts allow their tenants to load user `php.ini`. You *may* be able to get around this by using the `ini_set()` function in your `wp-config.php`:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
```

You might also want to set `max_execution_time` in case you're getting timed out before your upload completes.

Comment: I am sorry but the correct variable values are as shown now (I edited it a while ago) `post_max_size=100M`, `upload_max_file_size=100M` and `memory_limit=1280M`.
I did as you said, set max_execution_time to something bigger. But with no luck. I don't think the problem is with the execution time, the process stops right away without showing any sign of progress.